# Why are two elements of my inverse projection matrix always 0?

Tags: java, matrix, 3d, coordinate-transformation, projection-matrix

I'm writing a ray tracer for which I need to cast rays from the screen into the world. I'm using the inverse of the view-projection-viewport matrix to get back from screen pixel coordinates to world space coordinates.

I noticed by accident that two elements of the inverse matrix are always 0, no matter how or where I move, zoom, orbit, or spin the camera. I don't understand the projection matrix deeply enough to know why.

This is a hopefully-relevant portion of my Matrix class:

```
// OpenGL-style column-vectors layout.
public final class Matrix4 {
    public double e11, e12, e13, e14;
    public double e21, e22, e23, e24;
    public double e31, e32, e33, e34;
    public double e41, e42, e43, e44;
    
    public void transform(Vec3 v) {
        double x = v.x, y = v.y, z = v.z;
        double w = (x * e41) + (y * e42) + (z * e43) + (e44);
        double norm = 1 / w;
        v.x = ((x * e11) + (y * e12) + (z * e13) + (e14)) * norm;
        v.y = ((x * e21) + (y * e22) + (z * e23) + (e24)) * norm;
        v.z = ((x * e31) + (y * e32) + (z * e33) + (e34)) * norm;
    }
    
    public void perspectiveFovLH(double fovy, double aspect, double znear, double zfar) {
        double yscale = 1 / tan(fovy * 0.5);
        double xscale = yscale / aspect;
        double Q = zfar / (zfar - znear);
        
        e11 = xscale;
        e22 = yscale;
        e33 = Q;
        e34 = Q * -znear;
        e43 = 1;
    }
}
```

This is the view-projection-viewport matrix after moving the camera around for a while:

```
[ -331.62051997,  -616.31014741, -927.45531750,  354532.72229686
   158.60434983, -1091.70516425,  427.49500301,  420008.37868979
     0.75468455,    -0.51045982,   -0.41337968,     766.88486375
     0.75430721,    -0.51020459,   -0.41317299,     771.50142132 ]
```

And this is its inverse:

```
[ -0.00058203, -0.00019009,  113.94949731, -112.89669211
  -0.00033747, -0.00072765,  -84.29481494,   84.34162134
  -0.00064586,  0.00055151,  -61.14292715,   60.77360931
  -0.00000000, -0.00000000,   -0.19990000,    0.20000000 ]
```

Most of the elements change continuously as I move the camera. The two elements in the bottom right of the inverse seem to be directly related to the znear and zfar parameters. The two elements in the bottom left always seem to be constant 0.

This fact is useful in the transform method. If e41 and e42 are 0, and input z is always 0 or 1 when casting the near and far points of a ray into the screen, the w division can be computed ahead of time, rather than per-pixel. This is working and is a useful speedup.

However, I'm worried this assumption will break something later. So I'd like to know, what does it mean that these two elements are 0, and when will this assumption hold?

---

Edit: I [found out](https://www.brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html) that an affine 4x4 matrix has the last four elements (0 0 0 1). My inverse matrix almost matches up. But what is the magic that makes the inverse of a perspective matrix be affine, or, almost affine?

Comment: With affine matrices you were on the right track. This boils down to the fact that your pixels are rectangular. Read up on the viewing frustum and how it is related to the MVP.

Comment: This looks like a math question. You should formulate it mathematically and ask it on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Olivier There's no way I'd understand any answer they would give. It would be like TAOCP. I need an answer from programmers.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will help or distract you, but according to MS Direct3D 10 [D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-d3dxmatrixperspectivefovlh) function (replaced by [XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directxmath/nf-directxmath-xmmatrixperspectivefovlh) ), it should be `e34 = 1;` and `e43 = Q * -znear;`

Comment: @YogevNeumann That's fine. DirectX matrices have the transpose layout. I originally got the perspective matrix from Wine's implementation of the DirectX functions, but I use the OpenGL layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the given `perspectiveFovLH` matrix **P** and any homogeneous/affine transformation matrix **M**, the inverse **R**≔(**PM**)<sup>−1</sup> does **always** have *R*<sub>wx</sub>=*R*<sub>wy</sub>=0.

### Proof

To see this, let **t** be **Mv** for some input **v**, and let **s** be **Pt**=**PMv**, such that **v**=**Rs**.
Note that every **M** has *M*<sub>wx</sub>=*M*<sub>wy</sub>=*M*<sub>wz</sub>=0 and *M*<sub>ww</sub>=1, such that *t*<sub>w</sub>=*v*<sub>w</sub>.
Then observe from the sparseness of **P** that *s*<sub>w</sub>=*t*<sub>z</sub> and that

> *s*<sub>z</sub>=*Qt*<sub>z</sub> − *Qz*<sub>0</sub>*t*<sub>w</sub>
> =*Qs*<sub>w</sub> − *Qz*<sub>0</sub>*v*<sub>w</sub>

Solving the last equation yields

> *v*<sub>w</sub>=(*Qs*<sub>w</sub> − *s*<sub>z</sub>)/(*Qz*<sub>0</sub>)

This formula manifestly depends only on *s*<sub>z</sub> and *s*<sub>w</sub>, demonstrating as supposed that *R*<sub>wx</sub>=*R*<sub>wy</sub>=0.

### Rationale

We can understand this in a non-formulaic fashion: **3×4** matrices are sufficient for perspective on a screen, because you need only 2 output coordinates and the one homogeneous coordinate by which to divide them.  Using the full 4×4 matrix introduces a redundancy because both the *z* and *w* coordinates of the result derive only from the *z* coordinate of the input (and the known constant 1 for the initial *w*).  Regardless of the world transformation applied before the projection, you still have those two equations in the transformed *z* and the **original** *w*, which is enough to solve for them.

Comment: I'm really struggling to digest the math here, but thank you. Can I assume the inverse will always have elements wx = 0 and wy = 0 if those elements are also 0 in the original projection matrix? (And is that typical of any projection matrix??)

Comment: The proof relies both on `e41` and `e42` being 0 as established by `perspectiveFovLH` and on `e41`, `e42`, and `e43` being 0 in the camera position matrix (as described in your linked article).  Your [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Mathematical_formula) has that form because, as is common, you project along _z_ (after applying the camera position).  Note that "projection matrix" means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_projection) in general linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you. I don't fully follow the math but I trust your word. So I'm satisfied I can hard-code the dependence on e41=e42=0 in the inverse matrix without it being a practical limitation.